# why can we use empty brackets to initialize the std::function<void(Node*)> leave?

Tags: c++, c++11

The code snippet below is what I cannot understand:

```
extern void DFS(const Graph& g, std::function<void(Node*)> enter, 
                std::function<void(Node*)> leave);

DFS(*graph, visit, {}); // ***this is the call site***
```

So, the code above uses `{}` to initialize the `std::function<void(Node*)> leave`,
how to understand it?

Thanks very much, any information will be appreciated.

Comment: It default constructs the `leave` object. It's part of [*uniform initialization*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C%2B%2B11#Uniform_initialization).

Answer (score 1):

It relies on std::function empty ctor that creates an empty function.

See: http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/functional/function/function